# What's the practical use of pack/unpack and gather/scatter?

Tags: parallel-computing

In parallel programming, what is the practical use for pack/unpack and gather/scatter? I searched for practical examples and didn't find any use of those.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what these primitives are?

Comment: Pack/unpack and gather/scatter are project patterns for data management in parallel programming. I understood how they work, I just didn't find any use of them

Comment: Pack/unpack can be used to support denser in-memory formats that are expanded to a larger size for computation (to avoid overflow or support computation with other operands whose natural size is larger); most SIMD/vector instruction sets do not support mixed precision computation. Scatter/gather facilitates vectorization when an operand is at an arbitrary address, an extension of flexibility beyond stride addressing (which is itself an extension beyond unit stride addressing).